# event if keyboard is pressed outside of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).not('#inpa, #inpb').keydown(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 console.log('outside');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='inpa'>
<br><br>
<textarea id='inpb'></textarea>
```

I'm trying to triger some event if any keyboard button is pressed **and** cursor is not inside an input.

In the above case console is written regardless where is the cursor.

Comment: check `e.target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to check the `target` of the event (`e.target`) (which will give the dom element) and check if the `id` attribute is not in a list of input ids:

```js
var inputs = ['inpa', 'inpb'];
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
  if(inputs.indexOf(e.target.id) == -1) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('outside');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='inpa'>
<br><br>
<textarea id='inpb'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent event propagation via following code:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#inpa, #inpb', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do `$("input:not(#inpa), textarea:not(#inpb)")` . The [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector selects all elements except the specified element.

```js
$("input:not(#inpa), textarea:not(#inpb)").on('keydown', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 console.log('outside');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='inpa'>
<br><br>
<textarea id='inpb'></textarea>
<br><br>
<input type='text' value="for testing">
```